# How to solve "Invalid use of Function(<built-in function abs>)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I am trying to calculate gravity. The result should be a list, but the following error appeared:

> numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step:
>   nopython frontend)
>   Invalid use of Function(<built-in function abs>)
>   with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 1d, C))

```
@jit(nopython = True)
def gravity_calculator(x, y, h, dx, dy, p):
    calculated_gravity = np.array([])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        cal = 0
        for j in range(len(x)):
            x1 = abs((x[j] - x[i])+0.000001)
            x2 = x1 + dx
            y1 = abs((y[j]-y[i])+0.000001)
            y2 = y1 + dy
            t1 = np.log((y2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (y2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t2 = np.log((y1 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (y1 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t3 = np.log((y2 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (y2 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t4 = np.log((y1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (y1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t5 = np.log((x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t6 = np.log((x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t7 = np.log((x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t8 = np.log((x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t9 = np.arcsin(((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y2 * np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t10 = np.arcsin(((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y2 * np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y2 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t11 = np.arcsin(((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y1 * np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y1 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t12 = np.arcsin(((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y1 * np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            G = (x2 * (t1 - t2) - x1 * (t3 - t4) + y2 * (t5 - t6) - y1 * (t7 - t8) + h[j] * (t9 - t10 - t11 + t12))
            cal = cal +(p * G)
        calc = cal * 0.00667
        np.append(calculated_gravity,calc)
    return calculated_gravity

result = gravity_calculator(xi,yi,initial_depth,dx,dy,-0.4)
print(result)
```

Comment: Looks like `abs()` won't automatically spread over an array, so you'll need to write a loop that applies it to all the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

The abs() takes only one argument, a number whose absolute value is to be returned. The argument can be either an integer, a floating point number or a complex number.
Try:

```
np.absolute()
```

Comment: i try it and this happend:                                                       
    numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify Literal[int](0) and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'cal', defined at E:/Programming/Python/Python Projects/gravity_interpretation.py (101)

File "E:\Programming\Python\Python Projects\gravity_interpretation.py", line 101:
def gravity_calculator(x, y, h, dx, dy, p):
    <source elided>
    for i in range(len(x)):
        cal = 0

Comment: how about trying to define your own absolute function? def absolute(x, y)

Comment: just using np.absolute() worked,but this happened :     numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function iadd>) with argument(s) of type(s): (Literal[int](0), array(float64, 1d, C))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the input types to your function is, but I re-wrote it slightly as it appears you do not need `append` at all. Just pre-allocate your `calculated_gravity`  array to the correct size. This should also be generally faster, rather than appending:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def gravity_calculator(x, y, h, dx, dy, p):
    calculated_gravity = np.empty(len(x))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        cal = 0
        for j in range(len(x)):
            x1 = abs((x[j] - x[i])+0.000001)
            x2 = x1 + dx
            y1 = abs((y[j]-y[i])+0.000001)
            y2 = y1 + dy
            t1 = np.log((y2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (y2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t2 = np.log((y1 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (y1 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t3 = np.log((y2 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (y2 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t4 = np.log((y1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (y1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t5 = np.log((x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t6 = np.log((x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2))) / (x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t7 = np.log((x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (x2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t8 = np.log((x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2))) / (x1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t9 = np.arcsin(((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y2 * np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y2 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t10 = np.arcsin(((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y2 * np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y2 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t11 = np.arcsin(((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y1 * np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y1 + np.sqrt((x2 ** 2) + (y2 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            t12 = np.arcsin(((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2) + y1 * np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) / (
                        (y1 + np.sqrt((x1 ** 2) + (y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))) * np.sqrt((y1 ** 2) + (h[j] ** 2))))
            G = (x2 * (t1 - t2) - x1 * (t3 - t4) + y2 * (t5 - t6) - y1 * (t7 - t8) + h[j] * (t9 - t10 - t11 + t12))
            cal = cal +(p * G)
        calc = cal * 0.00667
        calculated_gravity[i] = calc
    return calculated_gravity


gravity_calculator_jit = nb.jit(nopython=True)(gravity_calculator)
```

and then I tested it using:

```
xi = np.random.normal(size=(10,))
yi = np.random.normal(size=(10,))
initial_depth = np.random.normal(size=(10,))
dx = 1.0
dy = 1.0

print(np.allclose(
    gravity_calculator(xi,yi,initial_depth,dx,dy,-0.4), 
    gravity_calculator_jit(xi,yi,initial_depth,dx,dy,-0.4)))
# True
```

Also note that when you were using `np.append(...)` in your original function, you would need to use it like:

```
calculated_gravity = np.append(calculated_gravity,calc)
```

since it does not operate in-place. See:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html